# How to check if any pdf file exists on server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, file-exists

Is it possible to check if any file with .pdf extension exists on server? I know i can use:
    File.Exists(Server.MapPath("/somepath")));
but this is when I'm looking for specific file. Is it possible to just look for the file extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can find all the files with certain extension, here is a sample code:

```
string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("/somepath"), "*.txt");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes that's it. So can you tell me if I want to delete all those files if they exists, how do I manage this? Thank you for your solution

Comment: Hay never mind I solved this with foreach function. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 0):

Currently i'm working with this Method:

```
public IEnumerable<FileInfo> FindFilesInDirectory(string dirPath)
{
    return Directory.Exists(dirPath)
               ? Directory.GetFiles(dirPath, "*.pdf", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                          .ToList()
                          .ConvertAll(x => new FileInfo(x))
               : null;
}
```

Not sure if it works with `Server.MapPath("/somepath")`